# How can I make my code go from one void to another in my menu code and get it to randomly generate inputs?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

My menu code (main) and the testMatrix code do not work properly, the menu code only improperly goes to the GetMatrix method (it has the user input a 4x4 matrix instead of the desired 3X4 and the testMatrix code doesn't even work, as it just uses the user input method instead. The program has asked me to change many of the program headers to make the code even run without crashing.

```
package sumelementsbycolumn;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumElementsByColumn 
{
        private final static Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //========================= void main() ==============================
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        char choice;
        do
        {
            final int ROWS = 3;
            final int COLUMNS = 4;
            double[][] matrix = new double[ROWS][COLUMNS];
            choice = getMenu();
            switch (choice) 
            {
                case '1': 
                {
                    matrix = GetMatrix(matrix);
                    sumColumn(matrix);
                    sumPrint(matrix);
                    break;
                }
                case '2': 
                {
                    matrix = testMatrix(matrix);
                    sumColumn(matrix);
                    sumPrint(matrix);
                    break;
                }
                case '0':
                    System.out.println("\n==================================");
                    System.out.println("\n=    Thank You for Using The     ="
                                     + "\nSum Elements By Column Determiner");
                    System.out.println("\n=            Goodbye!            =");
                    System.out.println("\n==================================");
            }
        }while(choice != '0');

    }

    //========================= char GetMenu() ===========================
    private static char getMenu() 
    {
        System.out.print("===================================\n"
                + "=Sum Elements By Column Determiner=\n"
                + "===================================\n\n"
                + "\t(1) Input 3 rows of integers\n"
                + "\t(2) Test system using random numbers\n"
                + "\t(0) Exit the program\n"
                + "Choose: ");
        char choice = myScan.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        return choice;

    }
    //========================= void sumPrint() ==============================
    private static void sumPrint(double[][] theMatrix)
        {

        // Read a 3-by-4 matrix
        final int ROWS = 3;
                final int COLUMNS = 4;
                double[][] matrix = new double[ROWS][COLUMNS];
                GetMatrix(matrix);

        // Display the sum of each column
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) 
                {   
            System.out.println(
                "Sum of the elements at column " + col + 
                " is " + sumColumn(matrix));
        }
    }
    //========================= double getMatrix() ===========================
    private static double[][] GetMatrix(double[][] matrix)
        {
            final int ROWS = 3;
            final int COLUMNS = 4;
            double[][] m = new double[ROWS][COLUMNS];

        // Prompt the user to enter a 3-by-4 matrix
            System.out.println("Enter a " + ROWS + "-by-" + 
            COLUMNS + " matrix row by row:");
            for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++)
                for (int col = 0; col < m[row].length; col++) 
                    m[row][col] = myScan.nextDouble();
                    while(!myScan.hasNextDouble())  
                    {
                        System.out.println("That is not a valid number!");
                        System.out.println("Re-Enter the Matrix Values: ");
                        myScan.next();
                    }
            return m;
    }

    //========================= double sumColumn() ===========================
    public static double sumColumn(double[][] m)
        {
        double sum = 0;
                int columnIndex = 0;
                for (double[] m1 : m) 
                {
                sum += m1[columnIndex];
                }
        return sum;
    }
    //========================= double testMatrix() ===========================
    private static double[][] testMatrix(double[][] blankMatrix)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();


        int count = 0;

            for (double[] blankMatrix1 : blankMatrix) 
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < blankMatrix.length; col++) 
                {
                    {
                        blankMatrix1[col] = rnd.nextInt(100);
                    }
                }
            }
        return blankMatrix;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tweaked the code a bit.This should work. Issue is in the sumColumn method that has the column index always set as 0.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SumElementsByColumn
{
    private final static Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //========================= void main() ==============================
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char choice;
        do
        {
            final int ROWS = 3;
            final int COLUMNS = 4;
            double[][] matrix = new double[ROWS][COLUMNS];
            choice = getMenu();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case '1':
                {
                    matrix = GetMatrix(matrix);
                   // sumColumn(matrix);
                    sumPrint(matrix);
                    break;
                }
                case '2':
                {
                    matrix = testMatrix(matrix);
                   // sumColumn(matrix);
                    sumPrint(matrix);
                    break;
                }
                case '0':
                    System.out.println("\n==================================");
                    System.out.println("\n=    Thank You for Using The     ="
                            + "\nSum Elements By Column Determiner");
                    System.out.println("\n=            Goodbye!            =");
                    System.out.println("\n==================================");
            }
        }while(choice != '0');

    }

    //========================= char GetMenu() ===========================
    private static char getMenu()
    {
        System.out.print("===================================\n"
                + "=Sum Elements By Column Determiner=\n"
                + "===================================\n\n"
                + "\t(1) Input 3 rows of integers\n"
                + "\t(2) Test system using random numbers\n"
                + "\t(0) Exit the program\n"
                + "Choose: ");
        char choice = myScan.next().toUpperCase().charAt(0);

        return choice;

    }
    //========================= void sumPrint() ==============================
    private static void sumPrint(double[][] theMatrix)
    {

        // Read a 3-by-4 matrix
        final int ROWS = 3;
        final int COLUMNS = 4;
       // double[][] matrix = new double[ROWS][COLUMNS];
        //GetMatrix(matrix);

        // Display the sum of each column
        for (int col = 0; col < theMatrix[0].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.println(
                    "Sum of the elements at column " + col +
                            " is " + sumColumn(theMatrix,col));
        }
    }
    //========================= double getMatrix() ===========================
    private static double[][] GetMatrix(double[][] matrix)
    {
        final int ROWS = 3;
        final int COLUMNS = 4;
        double[][] m = new double[ROWS][COLUMNS];

        // Prompt the user to enter a 3-by-4 matrix
        System.out.println("Enter a " + ROWS + "-by-" +
                COLUMNS + " matrix row by row:");
        for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < m[row].length; col++) {
                m[row][col] = myScan.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        while(!myScan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid number!");
            System.out.println("Re-Enter the Matrix Values: ");
            myScan.next();
        }
        return m;
    }

    //========================= double sumColumn() ===========================
    public static double sumColumn(double[][] m,Integer col)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int columnIndex = 0;

       // System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m));
        for (double[] m1 : m)
        {
           // System.out.println(" sumcolumn "+m1[col]);
            sum += m1[col];
        }
        return sum;
    }
    //========================= double testMatrix() ===========================
    private static double[][] testMatrix(double[][] blankMatrix)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();


        int count = 0;

        for (double[] blankMatrix1 : blankMatrix)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < blankMatrix.length; col++)
            {
                {
                    blankMatrix1[col] = rnd.nextInt(100);
                }
            }
        }
        return blankMatrix;
    }

}
```

Input Array for test:

```
===================================
=Sum Elements By Column Determiner=
===================================

    (1) Input 3 rows of integers
    (2) Test system using random numbers
    (0) Exit the program
Choose: 1
Enter a 3-by-4 matrix row by row:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

Output:

```
Sum of the elements at column 0 is 15.0
Sum of the elements at column 1 is 18.0
Sum of the elements at column 2 is 21.0
Sum of the elements at column 3 is 24.0
```